# Trying to open and create a new file, then changing all 4 letter words to "xxxxxx"

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replace four letter word in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284291/replace-four-letter-word-in-python)

For homework, I need to open a file, replace all four letter words with "xxxxxx", then write the text into a new file.

This is the file text in the original file that was given:

```
The 3 lines in this file end with the new line character.

There is a blank line above this line.
```

This is what I have so far:

```
def censor(filename):

    infile=open(filename,"r")

    content=infile.read()infile.close()

    outfile = open("censored.txt","w")

    content=content.replace("this","xxxxxx")

    content=content.replace("file","xxxxxx")

    content=content.replace("with","xxxxxx")

    content=content.replace("line","xxxxxx")

    outfile.write(content)

    outfile.close()
```

This is the result:

```
The 3 xxxxxxs in xxxxxx xxxxxx end xxxxxx the new xxxxxx character.

There is a blank xxxxxx above xxxxxx xxxxxx.
```

I'm having trouble getting just "line" and not "lines" to change, since at the moment "lines" is changing to "xxxxxxs".

Does anyone know of a particular way to do this? Will an if statement be needed?

Comment: I won't give the solution (it's homework after all). But read about [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

Comment: Learn how to use the [regular expression](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) module. A suitable regular expression and the [`re.sub`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) seems to be what you need.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13284291/replace-four-letter-word-in-python and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313778/python-3-2-replace-all-words-in-a-text-document-that-are-a-certain-length

Answer (score 1):

This will get you started.  This is not tested but it should solve the case where the word has punctuation.  It is also more robust because it iterates accommodates for files longer than 3 lines long, and it also removes any 4 letter word instead of only the ones you know about.

```
def censor(filename):
   infile = open(filename,"r")
   outfile = open("censored.txt","w")
   for line in infile:
       wordArr=line.split(" ");
       for word in wordArr:
           word = ''.join(c for c in string if c.isalnum())
           if len(word)==4:
               line=line.replace(word,"XXXXX")
       outfile.write(line)
   outfile.close()
   infile.close()
```

Others recommend using regex but I have to say this problem is easily solved without, so regex adds a decent amount of complexity.  especially for a new comer to programming.  However regex can be extremely useful and powerful to learn.

Answer (score 0):

```
content=content.replace("\\bline\\b","xxxxxx")
```

But it is VERY likely that your teacher doesn't want you to hard-code each four letter word in the snippet - he probably wants the code to work for ALLLL four letter words in ANY text file. This will require a different approach that I encourage you to think about (-=

Answer (score 0):

First, import re:

```
import re
```

Then replace all 4 successions of non spaces strings by xxxx :

```
content = re.sub(r"(\b)\w{4}(\b)", r"\1xxxxx\2", content)
```

Test it in a REPL :

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r"(\b)\w{4}(\b)", r"\1xxxxx\2", "Thes 3 lines in this file end with the new line character.")
'xxxxx 3 lines in xxxxx file end xxxxx the new xxxxx character.'
```